MATLAB `ordschur` producing different results from Lapack's `dtrsen` in Simulink
My question is very similar to the one previously posted here. I'm using the same MATLAB code for embedding Lapack functions into my code, which I also compiled with Mingw64. The main difference is that I'm calling the function from within a Simulink subsystems block, like so:
function p = fcn(A,B,Q,R,val_0)
coder.extrinsic("lapack");
coder.extrinsic("ordschur");
coder.extrinsic("cell2mat");
p = val_0;

s = max(size(A));

S = [A, -B/R*B'; -Q, -A'];
P = size(S,1);
WR = zeros(P,1);
WI = zeros(P,1);
WORK = zeros(P,1);
IWORK = zeros(P,1);

[Z,T] = schur(S);

SELECT = (real(ordeig(T)) < 0);

out3 = lapack('dtrsen','N','V',SELECT,P,T,P,Z,P,WR,WI,1,0,0,WORK,P,IWORK,1,1);
U = zeros(P,P);
U = cell2mat(out3(7))
cream = zeros(P,1);
cream = cell2mat(out3(9))


[U1,~] = ordschur(Z,T,"lhp")

potato = (U1 == U)
tomato = (cream == ordeig(T))

end

This is also a part of a sub-variant system for context. My main issue seems to lie in the fact that the vector containing my selected eigenvalues is ignored by the "lapack" function. The vector cream, which should return the list of ordered eigenvalues based on their left-plane position (and does so in a Matlab script) comes out unordered in the Simulink example. In the original question, some people suggested that the issue lies within Lapack's interpretation of the LOGICAL vs Matlab's BOOL.

A possible issue is that you are passing a vector of Matlab's bools as SELECT, while Fortran expects a logical value. Fortran's logical values do not necessarily map to 0 and 1 as in C or Matlab; rather, the mapping is compiler-dependent.


Federico Poloni (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/users/4405/federico-poloni)

However, I'm at a loss on how I could remedy this problem. I've attempted to recompile the lapack.c function, send the values in SELECT as int64, int32, int16, int8 (not accepted), logical, and even as strings (not accepted) to no avail.
Is this most likely a Simulink issue with no way around it? What other free compiler could I even try if Mingw64 isn't fit for this job?* I'm open to suggestions, I just don't really know how to proceed from here besides writing my own S-function (which I plan to eventually, but I'm currently short on time and I'm unsure whether it would work anyways).
I assume I've provided enough information, but if the need arises, I can provide more context/code. I can also add the information in the question I linked here if omitting it proves annoying/the question needs to be entirely self-contained.
*I tried CLANG64 but couldn't get Matlab to find it. I had to set a local environment variable for Mingw64 to be recognized too, but I don't know the environment variable I'd need to set for it to recognize CLANG64, and I'm not sure that even makes sense on Windows 10 as it is apparently a MAC thing?
